# Invoke-Command doesn't see local network drives

Tags: windows, powershell, process, remote-access, invoke-command

I have two computers: A and B. I'm trying to automate some CI\CD tasks, and my task is to start some process on B remotely, from A. The .exe file itself is on the `R` drive, which is a local network drive. So I do this:

```
# here $cred has encrypted credentials, but it is off topic...
Invoke-Command -ComputerName B -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    R:\WebClient\Platform\UP_110\Proc.exe
}
```

So apparently this would be the same thing as typing `R:\WebClient\Platform\UP_110\Proc.exe` on B's PowerShell and hitting Enter.

Now the problem is that I get this error when running the above code on A:

```
The term 'R:\WebClient\Platform\UP_110\Proc.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, sc
ript file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is corr
ect and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (R:\WebClient\Pl...IMS.UP.Host.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : B
```

Apparently it says that there is no such file as `R:\WebClient\Platform\UP_110\Proc.exe` on my B computer. But that is not true. I do have it:

[image]

As a matter of a fact, I have this R drive both on A and B.

The code works fine if I move the .exe to any directory under the `C` drive (which is the system disk for me), but not for `R`.
Now even funnier is that I can run `R:\WebClient\Platform\UP_110\Proc.exe` on A and B manually. And it works.

So what's the issue here I'm facing? Thanks.

Comment: Presumably the `R` drive is mapped when you log onto `A` or `B`, but running remote commands from `A` to `B` doesn't perform a full log on, so no drive.  You could use the [Copy-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.2#example-8-copy-a-file-to-a-remote-computer-and-then-rename-the-file) cmdlet to first copy the file to the remote server, or use the UNC path, though this might have the [double-hop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.2) issue.

Comment: @boxdog okay, I see. It's sad. Anyways, how do I use `Copy-Item` if I can't access the `R` drive?

Comment: You should be able to access the `R` drive by using its UNC name: `\\servername\sharename\WebClient\Platform\UP_110\Proc.exe`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but I thought you were running `Invoke-Command` from a system with the `R` drive defined to one without it, so you'd copy from there before running the remote command, which could then use the .exe on the remote system.  Just to be clear, the path you specify in the scriptblock for `Invoke-Command` is relative to the remote server, not the one issuing the command, so if you were thinking that it should be able to connect to `R` because you have it locally, that's not how it works.

Comment: @boxdog yeah, thanks for the clarification. Looks like I'll go with UNC then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell Remoting can only access drives by default that are mapped within the system context. Most commonly, this will be letter drives based on attached hardware (whether this be USB, SATA, SCSI, etc.).

Drives mapped in the *user* context, such as remote drives, are not mapped because a full logon does not occur the same way as if you log in locally. There are two workarounds you have at your disposal:

1. Use the UNC path when accessing files over an SMB/CIFS share (e.g. `\\server.domain.tld\ShareName\Path\To\Folder\Or\file.ext`
2. Map the drive within the `ScriptBlock` passed to `Invoke-Command` using [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?msclkid=96d77dd6d08b11ecb8630bc49aa76eb6&view=powershell-7.2):

   ```
   # Single letter drive name
   New-PSDrive -Name "R" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\server.domain.tld\ShareName"
   Get-ChildItem R:

   # More descriptive drive name
   New-PSDrive -Name "RemoteDrive" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\server.domain.tld\ShareName"
   Get-ChildItem RemoteDrive:
   ```

   Three things to note:

   - `Get-ChildItem` in the example above is to show that listing the contents of the new drives should show the files you expect to see at the remote directory. This can be omitted once you are sure it works for you.
   - Additionally, using a longer drive name is a *PowerShell* feature and does not mean that you can map shared folders as a drive from within File Explorer with more than a single character.
   - You may run into the double hop issue trying to map to a remote drive this way, if you are attempting to use the same credential you initiated `Invoke-Command` with. **Solving it properly is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow as this is a major architectural consideration for Active Directory**.

     *However*, you can work around it by building the credential object and passing it to
     `New-PSDrive` from within the `ScriptBlock`, or running `Invoke-Command` with
     `-Authentication CredSSP` if your organization does not block it (many do).